# Heisenberg's original Quantum Condition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

In Heisenberg's paper *Quantum Theoretical Re-interpretation of Kinematic and Mechanical Relations* where he first derives Quantum Mechanics, using his postulates of Quantum Mechanics and the Old Quantum condition $\oint p dq = nh$ he arrives at the Quantum Condition:
$$4\pi m\sum_{\alpha=0}^{\infty}\{|a(n,n+a)|^2\omega(n,n+a)-|a(n,n-a)|^2\omega(n,n-a)\}=h$$
which Born would eventually turn into the Canonical Commutation Relation.

But most explanations of Heisenberg's paper and even Heisenberg himself later in his paper list it as
$$4\pi m\sum_{\alpha=0}^{\infty}\{|a(n+a,n)|^2\omega(n+a,n)-|a(n,n-a)|^2\omega(n,n-a)\}=h$$
Which one is the correct one, and, if possible, could anyone point me towards the reasoning behind it?

Comment: it seems to be a formalism question and if Heisenberg adopted it, I would go with the second one. As one does not have the derivation, one cannot answer. maybe it is the same as the difference of $Ψ.Ψ*$  and  $Ψ*.Ψ$ .

Comment: Strange, I've tried using Heisenberg's derivation and, following his logic, it results in either $$4\pi m\sum_{\alpha=0}^{\infty}\{|a(n+a,n)|^2\omega(n+a,n)-|a(n,n-a)|^2\omega(n,n-a)\}=h$$Which seems to be the correct one, and $$-4\pi m\sum_{\alpha=0}^{\infty}\{|a(n,n+a)|^2\omega(n,n+a)+|a(n,n-a)|^2\omega(n,n-a)\}=h$$ Could it be a printing error in the original?